# failed to show the data of next date

Tags: jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5, webmethod

i am creating a web app in which i want to show the data of multiple dates

like

if i am executing my proc like`exec welcomepageproc 'admin','admin',''` all the data of today will be loaded

and if i execute my proc like `exec welcomepageproc 'admin','admin','1'` data will be shown of tomorrow(i.e 8 november) and if i execute my proc like exec welcomepageproc 'admin','admin','2' then the data of 9th november will be shown

data of today is showing properly but it is unable to show me the data of tomorrow

data of next date will be shown on the button click of next

this is my js file which is showing me today's data and working fine

```
  $http.get("welcome", "welcomepage", {
    params:
    {
        log: 'admin',
        pm: 'admin',
        button:''
    }
})
.then(function (response)
{
    $scope.welcometable = response.data;
    console.log(response.data);
})
```

but this js file is unable to show me data

```
    $scope.nextbutton = function () {
        $scope.button = '1';
        $http.get("welcome", "welcomepage", {
            params:
            {
                log: 'admin',
                pm: 'admin',
                button: '1'
            }
        })
   .then(function (response) {
       $scope.welcometable = response.data;
       console.log(response.data);
   })
```

and this is my next button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" ng-model="nextbuttons" ng-click="nextbutton()">Next</button>
```

and this is my `webmethod` in my controller

```
public JsonResult welcome(string log, string pm, string button)
    {
        log = "admin";
        pm = "admin";
        button = "0";

        List<object> welcome = new List<object>();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("welcomepageproc");
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter[] param =
        {
            new SqlParameter("@log",log),
            new SqlParameter("@pm",pm),
            new SqlParameter("@Button",button)
        };
        con.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            welcome.Add(new
            {
                date = dr["date"].ToString(),
                day = dr["day"].ToString(),
                Company = dr["Company"].ToString(),
                brandname = dr["Brand"].ToString(),
                zone = dr["zone"].ToString(),
                location = dr["location"].ToString(),
                area = dr["area"].ToString(),
                trainer = dr["trainer"].ToString(),
                starttime = dr["Start Time"].ToString(),
                endtime = dr["End Time"].ToString(),
                hrs = dr["hrs"].ToString(),
                program = dr["program"].ToString(),
                instructore = dr["instructore"].ToString()
            });
        }
        con.Close();
        var json = welcome;
        return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

what i need to do if i want to show next date on button click

(if i click on the next button twice then the data of 9th november should be shown and if i click 3 times the data of 10th will be shown, it means the data will be change on every next button click)

My sql storedprocedure

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE welcomepageproc  
(    
@log varchar(50),    
@pm varchar(50),    
@Button int    
)    

AS    
BEGIN    
declare @from varchar(50)    
select @from=Convert(varchar(20),getdate(),105)    

 declare @var varchar(50)    
 select @var=@log  
if(@button=null)  
begin   
if(@var='Partner Manager')    

begin    
 select convert(varchar,sonvininsert.date,105) as Date,    
sonvininsert.day as [Day],companydetails.comname as Company,sonvininsert.brandname as Brand,    
sonvininsert.zone as Zone,sonvininsert.location as Location,sonvininsert.area as Area,    
sonvininsert.trainer as Trainer,sonvininsert.starttime as [Start Time],sonvininsert.endtime as[End Time],    
sonvininsert.hrs as Hrs,sonvininsert.program as Program,sonvininsert.instructore as Instructore      
from sonvininsert,companydetails     
where companydetails.pm=@pm and companydetails.id=sonvininsert.property     
and sonvininsert.date = Convert(varchar(20),getdate()+@Button,101)    
and sonvininsert.status='0'  order by date    
end    

else if(@var='Admin')    
begin    
select convert(varchar,sonvininsert.date,105) as Date,    
sonvininsert.day as [Day],companydetails.comname as[Company],sonvininsert.brandname as[Brand],    
sonvininsert.zone as Zone,sonvininsert.location as Location,sonvininsert.area as Area,    
sonvininsert.trainer as Trainer,sonvininsert.starttime as[Start Time],sonvininsert.endtime as [End Time],    
sonvininsert.hrs as Hrs,sonvininsert.program as Program,sonvininsert.instructore as Instructore      
from sonvininsert,companydetails    
 where sonvininsert.date =Convert(varchar(20),getdate()+@Button,101)    
 and companydetails.id=sonvininsert.property    
 and sonvininsert.status='0'  order by date    
end    
end  
else  
begin  
if(@var='Partner Manager')    

begin    
 select convert(varchar,sonvininsert.date,105) as Date,    
sonvininsert.day as [Day],companydetails.comname as Company,sonvininsert.brandname as Brand,    
sonvininsert.zone as Zone,sonvininsert.location as Location,sonvininsert.area as Area,    
sonvininsert.trainer as Trainer,sonvininsert.starttime as [Start Time],sonvininsert.endtime as[End Time],    
sonvininsert.hrs as Hrs,sonvininsert.program as Program,sonvininsert.instructore as Instructore      
from sonvininsert,companydetails     
where companydetails.pm=@pm and companydetails.id=sonvininsert.property     
and sonvininsert.date = Convert(varchar(20),getdate()+@Button,101)    
and sonvininsert.status='0'  order by date    
end    

else if(@var='Admin')    
begin    
select convert(varchar,sonvininsert.date,105) as Date,    
sonvininsert.day as [Day],companydetails.comname as[Company],sonvininsert.brandname as[Brand],    
sonvininsert.zone as Zone,sonvininsert.location as Location,sonvininsert.area as Area,    
sonvininsert.trainer as Trainer,sonvininsert.starttime as[Start Time],sonvininsert.endtime as [End Time],    
sonvininsert.hrs as Hrs,sonvininsert.program as Program,sonvininsert.instructore as Instructore      
from sonvininsert,companydetails    
 where sonvininsert.date =Convert(varchar(20),getdate()+@Button,101)    
 and companydetails.id=sonvininsert.property    
 and sonvininsert.status='0'  order by date    
end  
end  
END
```

Comment: provide the sql query of your stored pro

Comment: @NewbeeDev EDITED MY QUESTION

Comment: is this sql server? did you try manually putting `exec welcomepageproc 'admin','admin','1'` in your dbms does it have the correct result?

Comment: yes and it is working and i put that in my question

Comment: so the only problem is the date tomorrow?

Comment: yes the tomorrow date is the only problem

Comment: can you provide your table structure and sample data. also did you try displaying the value of your parameter button and check if it is correct.